# Understanding jQuery build from Github. Can't Understand Concatenation of jQuery using Gruntjs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand jQuery source code. On the [jQuery GitHub Repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) it builds jQuery files using GruntJS. After having a look at the GruntJS file in jQuery Repository if found that there is no concatenation task defined. However there is a call to

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

which is used to run tasks from npm.

Going through some intro on Grunt [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format), it describes how should the concatenation task be defined. But I can't find any such code in jQuery repo.

Can somebody explain me how the jQuery code is being assembled? It will allow me to separate the modules and have a look at them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I was dumbfounded at too when I saw it first time.

Here's your answer: [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks). Just as jit-grunt, this task takes care of calling loadNpmTasks for each and every **grunt-** module you use (this one via globbing, jit, well, just-in-time).

As for the order of compilation, take a look at the tasks:

```
// Integrate jQuery specific tasks
grunt.loadTasks( "build/tasks" );

grunt.registerTask( "lint", [ "jshint", "jscs" ] );

// Short list as a high frequency watch task
grunt.registerTask( "dev", [ "build:*:*", "lint" ] );

// Default grunt
grunt.registerTask( "default", [ "jsonlint", "dev", "uglify", "dist:*", "compare_size" ] );
```

First as you can see additional tasks are loaded from build/tasks folder. Default task is executed when you simply run "grunt".

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

Doesn't run tasks, it just loads them.

Comment: I found that too.. The problem is I can't find any config details in which the order of the file compilation is written.